# How to add a native extension to Flash develop 4.5 +

Tags: flash, air, flashdevelop, adobe-native-extensions, ane

when i tried to include an ane file in flash develop and run the application i was getting error "The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension Error : requested extension com.adobe.extensions.Vibration could not found."

when i search on google, i got many result "http://winxalex.blogspot.in/2012/04/native-extension-template-flash-develop.html" like these types of pages from flash develop and some other blogs. when i tried all those steps, could not able to find out any solution for the above mentioned error.

is possible somebody can share a working sample using flash develop 4.5 or above.

when i search for a sample working project. i could not able to find it out.